# Zend\Mail ignores copy recipients (BCC or CC)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3, zend-mail

When trying to send a message with `Zend\Mail` to multiple `BCC` or `CC` recipients, only the first recipient in the list will receive the email. Multiple normal recipients aren't a problem.

```
$mail = new Mail\Message();
$mail->setBcc([
    'bcc_recipient_one@example.com',
    'bcc_recipient_two@example.com',
    'bcc_recipient_three@example.com',
]);
```

It doesn't make a difference to use `setBcc` or `addBcc` of the `Message` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Issue**

The problem belongs to a wrong format of the `Zend\Mail` header generation. It uses `line-breaks` between all `CC` or `BCC` recipients. As fully described in [this post](https://daker.de/post/detail/2018/32/zend-mail-has-problems-with-multiple-bcc-recipients.html), the workaround is to fix the folding.

For example, this snippet:

```
$mail = new Mail\Message();
$mail->setFrom('test@stackoverflow.com', 'Stackoverflow Tester');
$mail->addTo('email@stackoverflow.com', 'Stackoverflow  Recipient');
$mail->setSubject('Stackoverflow Test');
$mail->setBcc(['bcc_one@so.com', 'bcc_two@so.com', 'bcc_three@so.com']);
```

Will create such header:

```
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2018 19:11:36 +0100
From: Stackoverflow Tester <test@stackoverflow.com>
To: email@stackoverflow.com
Subject: Stackoverflow Test
Bcc: bcc_one@so.com,
 bcc_two@so.com,
 bcc_three@so.com
```

The problem, for at least some servers (like Micrsoft Exchange), is the line-breaks after the recipients. To fix this issue, the best way IMO would be an own Header class, because the line-breaks are hard-coded in Zend\Mail.

**The Solution**

Just copy `\Zend\Mail\Header\Bcc` class to your module and overwrite the `getFieldValue` function in there. With this approach you will be stay compatible on updates in the future.

```
public function getFieldValue($format = HeaderInterface::FORMAT_RAW)
{
    $value = parent::getFieldValue($format);
    return str_replace(Headers::FOLDING, ' ', $value);
}
```

The recipients will now be passed by the new header class to the `Message` object.

```
$bcc = new \MyModule\Header\Bcc();
$bcc->getAddressList()->addMany(['bcc_one@so.com', 'bcc_two@so.com', 'bcc_three@so.com']);
$mail->getHeaders()->addHeader($bcc);
```

That's it, the new header will be generated correctly:

```
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2018 19:11:36 +0100
From: Stackoverflow Tester <test@stackoverflow.com>
To: email@stackoverflow.com
Subject: Stackoverflow Test
Bcc: bcc_one@so.com, bcc_two@so.com, bcc_three@so.com
```

For more details about the issue and the solution, [take a look to the original post](https://daker.de/post/detail/2018/32/zend-mail-has-problems-with-multiple-bcc-recipients.html).